# Sparql query using ASK WHERE based on COUNT result

Tags: count, subquery, sparql

I have the following basic query, which retrieves how many paintings were done by an artist

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>  
SELECT (COUNT(?numberOfPaintings) AS ?howMany)  
WHERE  {  ?numberOfPaintings dc:creator "Artists_Name" . }
```

The variable `?howMany` returns, let's say 20 (paintings) — so far, so good. I'd like to create another query that would use `ASK WHERE` to check whether the artist has painted more than 10 paintings, with an expected result of `true` or `false`.

I have tried using `?numberOfPaintings > 10` in the `ASK` portion of the query and I know I still need to do the `COUNT`, but so far I have only seen the `>` operator in the context of the `FILTER` function so I am not sure how to use it in other situations such as this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A alternative, with much the same effect: `HAVING` is the way to apply a filter after an aggregation operation:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>  
SELECT (COUNT(?numberOfPaintings) AS ?howMany)  
WHERE  {  ?numberOfPaintings dc:creator "Artists_Name" . }
HAVING ( ?howMany > 7 )
```

and then you can embed inside an `ASK` query.

Comment: This is a better solution than [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19826912/1281433). I use HAVING so rarely, that I forgot about it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate seeing both scenarios. I forgot about the "having" too!

Answer (score 4):

> **Note: [AndyS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19833321/1281433) is better for this specific scenario.  While the nested `select` query and filter expressions that I've used here might be necessary for more complex query restrictions, this particular case can be solved more easily with `having`.**

Let's say you've got data like this:

```
@prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826515/> .

:a1 :p :b1, :b2, :b3 .
:a2 :p :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4 .
:a3 :p :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5 .
```

Then a query like:

```
select ?a (count(?b) as ?num) where {
  ?a :p ?b 
}
group by ?a
```

returns each `?a` and the number of its `?b`s:

```
-------------
| a   | num |
=============
| :a3 | 5   |
| :a1 | 3   |
| :a2 | 4   |
-------------
```

Now you just need to wrap that query in another query and filter on `?num > ...`.  E.g,. for `3`:

```
prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826515/>
ask where { 
  {
    select ?a (count(?b) as ?num) where {
      ?a :p ?b 
    }
    group by ?a
  }
  filter( ?num > 3 )
}
```

```
Yes
```

For `7`, we'll get no:

```
prefix : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826515/>
ask where { 
  {
    select ?a (count(?b) as ?num) where {
      ?a :p ?b 
    }
    group by ?a
  }
  filter( ?num > 7 )
}
```

```
No
```